# Could not bind factory to JNDI Need to specify class name in environment or system property

Tags: hibernate

---

Hi ,

I'm trying to run an imported open source but i'm getting this error after running : it's driving me crazy it's a huge project and i don't know from i should start .

```
Running test.hibernate.softdelete.jointablewhere.SoftDeleteAssociationTest
main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] - configuring from resource: softdelete/softdelete-hibernate.cfg.xml

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] - Configuration resource: softdelete/softdelete-hibernate.cfg.xml

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] - Configured SessionFactory: java:hibernate/SessionFactory

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] - Binding entity from annotated class: test.hibernate.softdelete.jointablewhere.Parent

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder] - Bind entity test.hibernate.softdelete.jointablewhere.Parent on table Parent

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] - Binding entity from annotated class: test.hibernate.softdelete.jointablewhere.Child

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder] - Bind entity test.hibernate.softdelete.jointablewhere.Child on table Child

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.search.HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister] - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.

main INFO [org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider] - Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)

main INFO [org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider] - Hibernate connection pool size: 20

main INFO [org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider] - autocommit mode: false

main INFO [org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider] - using driver: org.h2.Driver at URL: jdbc:h2:mem:softdelete

main INFO [org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider] - connection properties: {user=sa, password=****}

main INFO [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

main INFO [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.JdbcSupportLoader] - Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Database ->
       name : H2
    version : 1.2.144 (2010-10-15)
      major : 1
      minor : 2

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Driver ->
       name : H2 JDBC Driver
    version : 1.2.144 (2010-10-15)
      major : 1
      minor : 2

main INFO [org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory] - Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)

main INFO [org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory] - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - JDBC batch size: 15

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Scrollable result sets: enabled

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Connection release mode: auto

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Default batch fetch size: 1

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Generate SQL with comments: disabled

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory

main INFO [org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Query language substitutions: {}

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Second-level cache: enabled

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Query cache: disabled

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Statistics: disabled

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Default entity-mode: pojo

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Named query checking : enabled

main INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Check Nullability in Core (should be disabled when Bean Validation is on): disabled

main INFO [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl] - building session factory

main INFO [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory] - Factory name: java:hibernate/SessionFactory

main INFO [org.hibernate.util.NamingHelper] - JNDI InitialContext properties:{}

main WARN [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory] - Could not bind factory to JNDI
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getNameParser(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.util.NamingHelper.bind(NamingHelper.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory.addInstance(SessionFactoryObjectFactory.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:367)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$buildSessionFactory.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at test.hibernate.softdelete.jointablewhere.SoftDeleteAssociationTest.setup(SoftDeleteAssociationTest.groovy:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invokeRaw(BaseSpecRunner.java:235)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:217)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invokeSetup(BaseSpecRunner.java:198)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runSimpleFeature(BaseSpecRunner.java:181)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.doRunFeature(BaseSpecRunner.java:174)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invokeRaw(BaseSpecRunner.java:235)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:217)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runFeature(BaseSpecRunner.java:152)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runFeatures(BaseSpecRunner.java:129)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.doRun(BaseSpecRunner.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invokeRaw(BaseSpecRunner.java:235)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:217)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.run(BaseSpecRunner.java:73)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik.run(Sputnik.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.execute(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.invoke(JUnitCoreProvider.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
    at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)

main INFO [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl] - closing

main INFO [org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider] - cleaning up connection pool: jdbc:h2:mem:softdelete

main INFO [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory] - Unbinding factory from JNDI name: java:hibernate/SessionFactory

main INFO [org.hibernate.util.NamingHelper] - JNDI InitialContext properties:{}

main WARN [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory] - Could not unbind factory from JNDI
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

here's the softdelete-hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<!-- a SessionFactory instance listed as /jndi/name -->
<session-factory name="java:hibernate/SessionFactory">
    <!-- properties -->
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:mem:softdelete</property>
    <property name="connection.driver">org.h2.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="connection.password">sa</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.import_files">softdelete/import.sql</property>
    <property name="validator.apply_to_ddl">false</property>
    <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</property>
</session-factory>
   </hibernate-configuration>
```

Any idea please ?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 22):

In softdelete-hibernate.cfg.xml, remove the session-factory name.
Try using only

```
<session-factory>
   <!-- ... -->
</session-factory>
```

Answer (score 15):

Just remove the `name` from    `<session-factory`name="SessionFactory"`>`